# Constructing a Container for the Given Situation

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, sets, c++

I need to make a container in which I can store (x,y) as pairs, and for a given number 'a', I have to find a pair (p, q) such that p<=a and q is maximum possible.
Note the constraints: x>=1 and x<= 10^7; y >=1 and y<=10^5.

I am solving this problem in C++.

I tried using a set that stores pairs of integers. I was able to find p by using binary search over set, but I was not able to ensure maximum q condition.

Edit: it is a dynamic problem.

Thanks.

Comment: 1) Sort all your points by $p$.
2) Calculate prefix maximums by $q$.
3) For each query find the rightmost element with $p \leq a$ and lookup precalculated prefix maximum for this position.

Comment: Is the problem static or dynamic?

Comment: @Russel it is dynamic.

Comment: Dynamic in what sense? Are queries $a$ dynamic or pairs $(x,y)$ be dynamically inserted or deleted? How many queries $a$ can be there? What time complexity you are aiming for? Did you try $BST$ or segment trees?

Comment: Please also mention where you encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the staircase formed by the "left-dominant" points, i.e. those such that they have the maximum ordinate among the points to their left. (If I am right, this staircase is the analogue of the convex hull but for the Manhattan metric.)

[image]

A dynamic solution to this problem is known, based on an augmented binary search tree. https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/BF02187797.pdf

For a given $a$, the $(p,q)$ solution is the vertex immediately to the left of $a$, which can be found by searching the tree.